Getting the issue while creating the project by using React Native Expo, ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\'C:'
I am new to React Native mobile application. I have installed node JS and React Native Expo. while creating the project getting the below issue
ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\'C:'

Please find the screenshot for the issue

Here what was the issue
